# app.config modification doesn`t change the actual database connection

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to test a basic, primitive Flask todo-app that uses SQLAlchemy.

the problem is that I change app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] to anything in test file, the environmental variable changes during testing but commits are still performed on a main database which was specified in main.py. I tried different approaches - modifying uri through os.environ, using Flask-Testing package, positioning modification of config before import statement but unittest still uses main database and modifies it. I used print statements to check the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI and it indeed changes but makes no effect. What am I doing wrong?

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    todo_list = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template("base.html", todo_list=todo_list)


@app.route("/add", methods=["POST"])
def add():
    title = request.form.get("title")
    new_todo = Todo(title=title, complete=False)
    db.session.add(new_todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


@app.route("/update/<int:todo_id>")
def update(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).first()
    todo.complete = not todo.complete
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


@app.route("/delete/<int:todo_id>")
def delete(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).first()
    db.session.delete(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        app.run(debug=True)
```

test_main.py

```
from main import db, app, Todo
import unittest


class TodoTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app.config["TESTING"] = True
        app.config["WTF_CSRF_ENABLED"] = False
        app.config["DEBUG"] = False
        app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///:memory:"
        self.app = app.test_client()
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        self.create_todo()
        self.assertEqual(app.debug, False)

    def create_todo(self):
        item = Todo(title="Todo")
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()

    def test_todo_endpoint(self):
        response = self.app.get("/")
        # print (response.data)
        self.assertIn(
            b'Todo', response.data
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: you are initializing the app on main, whatever changes you do after that will not be reflected, you have to use "application factories" as seen here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appfactories/

for having different urls for testing and production, you can refer https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/

Comment: ok, thank you, I was thinking of that, but seeing some similar code like mine made me think that testing could be done easily